# What causes different behaviors in Chrome - IE and Firefox in this very simple Java app running on Tomcat?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, unicode, encoding

I have a very simple Java web application running on Tomcat 8.5.4. Here are my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And **web.xml** is as follows..

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

and all I have is 2 Servlets:

**UTF16.java**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/utf16")
public class UTF16 extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.print("<!doctype html>\n" +
                     "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
                     "<head>\n" +
                         "<meta charset=\"utf-16\"/>");
        writer.print("</head>\n");
        writer.print("<body>");
        writer.print('\u20ac'); // This is the unicode code point for the Euro sign.
        writer.print("<body>");
        writer.print("</html>");
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

and **UTF32.java** looks very similar..

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/utf32")
public class UTF32 extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-32");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.print("<!doctype html>\n" +
                     "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
                     "<head>\n" +
                         "<meta charset=\"utf-32\"/>");
        writer.print("</head>\n");
        writer.print("<body>");
        writer.print('\u20ac'); // This is the unicode code point for the Euro sign.
        writer.print("<body>");
        writer.print("</html>");
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

This is what I get in Chrome for urls **/utf16** and **/utf32** respectivly..

[image]

[image]

Now try Internet Explorer (v11.0.96... something..)

For **/utf16**
[image]

For **/utf32**
[image]

What?

**Firefox** will return the **same result with Chrome for /utf16** and **same result for /utf32 with Internet Explorer**.

What is going on?

In case related, this is what a simple HTTP Headers capture plugin will capture:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-16
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 12:57:48 GMT
```

Why is Internet Explorer showing me some Chinese text for /utf16 and does not parse the HTML for /utf32 and shows it as just plain text?

**A small edit..**
I tried with Jetty to make sure the issue is not related to Tomcat, and all outputs are same on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer had [some problems with encodings before](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928847/internet-explorer-uses-the-wrong-character-set-when-it-renders-an-html-page). Microsoft provides some workarounds, try them:

> To resolve this issue, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Disable the Auto-Select setting in Internet Explorer.
> - Provide the character set in the HTTP headers.
> - Move the META tag to within the first kilobyte of data that is parsed by MSHTML. Although we do not know how much data the parser reads at a time, this location will resolve the issue.
> - Increase the size of the server's initial HTTP response. The initial size should be at least 1 KB.
> - Make sure that the System Locale setting matches the character set of the META tag that is specified in the HTML page.

Also your `<meta charset="utf-16"/>` is the HTML5 way. I couldn't check anywhere if it's supported by IE11 or not, but using the old `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-16">` declaration may be also worth a try.